# Why are some pages showing Google Adsense Blank Ads?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

I have a site where I've implemented Google Adsense. On most of the pages, the ads are showing fine but on one page it is showing empty space. What is the reason for that?

Comment: It is impossible to say from just the information your provide.  It could be an implementation problem or just that Google doesn't have ads to show on those pages.